# iPad webapp flashes when launched from springboard, fine in Safari browser

Tags: ipad, web-applications, safari, iphone-standalone-web-app, springboard

I'm developing a site for tablets (testing on iPad) using jquery mobile and I've enabled it to be a full screen web app using `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`

Works quite nicely, but when you navigate to a new page, there's a momentary flash which takes up 3/4 of the screen. There's no flash when browsing using it in standard mode safari.

The flash is very distracting and unusable.

Answer (score 2):

The fullscreen "webapp" view that iOS uses gets less power to play with (ram,...) than the real mobile safari.

If you combine that with a lot of javascript going on in the background, you will get delays and page flickers.

I noticed jQuery mobile has a lot of performance issues in that fullscreen view, especially with the so called "fixed header and footer" on older iOS devices.

Try simplifying the javascript you use, and start adding functionalities from there.

Comment: I did try removing all the js I could, but it still happened. I've had to work on another project but will come back to this in a few months. I just wanted to thank you for your response as it sounds a likely reason for it not working.